# Is there a way to change passphrase prompt for ssh?

Tags: ssh, login, default, prompt

I wanted to change the prompt for ssh login,

```
Enter passphrase for key 'path/to/key':
```

to something else. Is that possible?

Sorry I'm not really sure on the right verbiage, but I don't mean the PS1 variable prompt. More so the prompt that's (sort of) the question that asks for the key passphrase

I'm using RSA authentication

**UPDATE**: made changes to sshconnect2.c and recompiled after cloning from the openssh git repo
Thanks, steeldriver and Klaus D.

Comment: Could you clarify a bit. That "prompt" is not a "prompt" in the normal sense. That is happening client side before the connection is even made (most likely).

Comment: Sure, I'm a little shaky on terminology, so I apologize

Comment: I don't think there's any way to change it directly - it's baked into the openssh-client source code (sshconnect2.c) `"Enter passphrase for key '%.100s': ", id->filename);`

Comment: So, the way to go would be to change the source and recompile.

Comment: Ok thanks, I'll try that. And I'm guessing that's on the client side?

Comment: Can I ask why you would want to change the prompt?

Comment: Got it, thanks for the help. Although I had to set an alias due to privilege issues on OSX. 

@RyanJ.Yoder - I really don't know what else to say other than I wanted to lol